c# MultipartFormDataContent, File path without access to file
I am using this code to send a list of file paths to a api and receive response from api.
But it is not working. I do not have access to the file. The file is only available to the api. A user like me cannot open the file directly, so this line fails. The api has access to the file, processes it and sends me the response. How should I modify this code to take only filepath and not the byte[] arrray content
var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePathList[i]));

Code
using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    // Load the file and add it to the form data
    for (int i = 0; i < filePathList.Count; i++)
    {
        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePathList[i]));
        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/pdf");
        form.Add(fileContent, "file", "one.pdf");
    }

    // Set headers
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);

    // Post the form data to the API
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, form);
    Console.WriteLine($"Response received with status code: {response.StatusCode}");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Request successful. Reading response content...");

        // Read and return the response body
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Response content read successfully.");
        
        return responseBody;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Request failed with status code: {response.StatusCode}");
        string errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"Error content: {errorContent}");
        throw new HttpRequestException($"Request failed with status code: {response.StatusCode}, content: {errorContent}");
    }


Never mind. I got it to work     string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filePathList, Formatting.Indented);
// Post the form data to the API
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(
url,
new StringContent(
json,
Encoding.UTF8,
"application/json"));
